# How do I get the SelectedItems as list to ViewModel in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have an issue with getting the `SelectedItems` from my `DataGrid`.

This is my `DataGrid`. I have set the `SelectionMode=Extended` so that I can retrieve all selected items.

```
<DataGrid Name="ConcentratorGrid"
              SelectionMode="Extended"                  
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSettings, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Concentrators}"
              >
```

The `SelectedItem` is binded to this:

```
 public ConcentratorSettings SelectedSettings
    {
        get { return _selectedSettings; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _selectedSettings)) return;
            _selectedSettings = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedSettings);
        }
    }
```

And the `ItemSource` is this

```
 public ObservableCollection<ConcentratorSettings> Concentrators { get; set; }
```

Now I want to trigger with a button click and get the `SelectedItems`, I have not been able to do that with the following `Caliburn.Micro` syntax.

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="UploadToConcentrators">
                        <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=ConcentratorGrid, Path=SelectedItems}" />
                    </cal:ActionMessage>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

The method that is used with this button is this with the first one as a guard

```
 public bool CanUploadToConcentrators(IList concentrators)
    {
        return concentrators?.Count > 0;
    }

    public void UploadToConcentrators(IList concentrators)
    {}
```

I hope that someone know how to get the selectedItems to that method without use of a Command.

PS. This is my first post on StackOverFlow, so if this is not informative enough please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please avoid stuffing keywords into the title, unless they are natural part of the question title. See the help center  on use of tags http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: Welcome ! I upvoted you as a welcome gift

Comment: The binding on `SelectedItem` is configured as one way. In other words any changes in selection by the user won't be reflected in the value of `SelectedItem` but the initial value of `SelectedItem` will be shown in the grid.

Comment: Thanks for the comments :)
Jack I want to get all the selecteditems from the datagrid to my viewmodel. tried the different SelectedItem modes, but didnt help ;(

Comment: Apparently it is my guard that isnt working, if I comment that out and try and hit the button. the list is correctly moved to my viewmodel.